# Где хранятся встроенные PHP-функции?

Tags: php

Привет.

1. В PHP есть много встроенных функций. Мне не понятно, ГДЕ они хранятся. Например, есть функция `strlen`, которой отдается строка, а она возвращает ее длину в виде числа целого.

Например, я пишу `$str="qwe";echo(strlen($str));` . Внутри ЧЕГО (массив, объект...) хранится функция `strlen`? Напрмиер, `$str` хранится внутри массива `$GLOBALS` и скрипт `$str="qwe";` можно переписать, как `$GLOBALS["$str"]="qwe";`

2. Где хранятся встроенные константы? Например, `E_ALL`.

Comment: В библиотеках (`dll`/`so`)?

Comment: В исполняемом файле интерпретатора PHP они могут храниться и наверняка хранятся.

Comment: PHP распространяется с исходным кодом (написан на языке C), если интересно - скачайте исходники и посмотрите там. для обозначеных вами вещей нет никаких объектов самого языка PHP к которым вы привыкли, это в совершенно другом виде отражено в C коде

Answer (score 3):

Исходя из приведенного вами примера вы говорите об области видимости.

Встроенные функции находятся в глобальной области видимости и доступны из любой части программы. Если вы используете пространства имен, для доступа к встроенным функция нужно использовать префикс \ - \strlen()

Comment: Впервые слышу, что бы префикс использовался для нативных функций. Для строенных классов и интерфейсов - да.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.basics.php
http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.fallback.php